# Non-constructive proof for a prime $p, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z+}, a\equiv b\pmod {p^k}\implies a\equiv b\pmod p.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As a simple case take $k=2, a\equiv b\pmod {p^2}\implies a\equiv b\pmod p.$

 A constructive example for $a= 2, b=27, p =5$ will work, but needed is a general or non-constructive approach, so as to get the reasoning applicable generally in a formal manner.

I mean the reason for the no change in residue class, for a root of the modulus is not clear.

I can only work out the case when $a , b \lt p$, as it is the trivial case (with $a=b$) for the smaller modulus case.

Comment: What could possibly be "non-constructive" about a proof of this (which just amounts to noting that $p\mid p^k$)?

Comment: I wonder what you think "non-construction proof" means.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown For me your statement is a non-constructive proof, in a verbal manner.

Comment: @fleablood One that does not take only an example to prove for failure or success, but takes an algebraic or symbolic approach.

Comment: This is trivial.  If $p^2|a-b $ and $p|p^2$ then $p|a-b $.   p doesn't have to be prime and we don't have to square it.  If $a\equiv b \mod nk $ then $a\equiv b\mod n $.  I'm pretty sure you prove that last week.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, but last week it was for $a\equiv b \pmod n \implies a^i \equiv b^i \pmod n$. And I harped on the derivation of the second equality/expression from the original one, and your argument was that it does not matter how the second expression is derived from the first.

Comment: I was talking more about a basic prove that if $a|b$ and $b|c $ then $a|c $.  This question is *absolutely* the *exact* same.

Comment: @fleablood Sorry for not being able to detect that it is the same case of transitive property of division.

Comment: I don't think "constructive" means what you think it means.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Please help me find fault with my understanding of 'constructive proof', by elaborating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a \equiv b \pmod{p^k}$$

$$a-b \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}$$

$$\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}, (a-b) =p^km$$

$$\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}, (a-b) =p(p^{k-1}m)$$

$$a-b \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I request that the failure for the converse case be proved by such (non-constructive) approach. I mean that given $a\equiv b \pmod {p} \nrightarrow a \equiv b \pmod {p^k}$.

Comment: scratch head, to disprove it, I just need a counter example... I dont get what is non-constructive.

Comment: I mean that there should be an algebraic proof, but as in converse the hypothesis and conclusion are exchanged; and given the implication in the original - so, assuming hypothesis is H, conclusion is C; we have originally: $\lnot H \cup C$, and for converse, it is: $\lnot C \cup H$. $H: a\equiv b \pmod {p^k}$, $C: a\equiv \pmod p$. So, have: $\lnot (a\equiv b \pmod p) \cup H$. And need to prove it false, as a general case. Also, $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, a \equiv b \pmod p \implies (a-b) = kp$

Comment: $p \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ but $p \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}, k>1$.

Comment: I hope yours is till a constructive example, just not using an actual value to substitute for. May be I am wrong, as if a general case is taken then it is non-constructive. Confused. But, one thing is certain that it is still showing a counter-case.

Comment: Please help with an  EDITED version of the proof for converse case at below hyperlink address, and help as it is stuck: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651730/prove-for-a-prime-p-forall-l-in-mathbb-z-a-equiv-b-pmod-p-nrightarrow

Answer (score 1):

If $a|b $ and $b|c $ then $a|c $.  (Because if there exist $k $ so that $b=a*k $ and if there is a $m $ so that $c=b*m$, then $c=a (k*m) $

So if $a\equiv b\mod p^2$ that means $p^2|a-b $.  And since $p|p^2$ we know $p|a-b $