# Correct existential clauses to be used in an implication.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, alternative-proof, quantifiers

It is provable by contrapositive, as below (after the post): 
If $((r \mid s),$ & $(r \nmid t))$, then $s\nmid t$,
 i.e., $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, s=kr, \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, t\ne ms \implies \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, t\ne mkr$. 
I mean that what should be the correct existential clauses to be used in conclusion.

It seems more correct to ignore $k$ in conclusion, i.e.,  $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}, s=kr, \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, t\ne ms \implies \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}, t\ne mr$. 
The meaning should be that for all values of $m$ the relation is not satisfied, & $k$ is immaterial here.

---

Need prove that $r\mid s \wedge r\nmid t \nrightarrow s\nmid t$.
Assume that the implication has the form $H\nrightarrow C$, with $H$ being compound, i.e. it is composed of $P\wedge Q$, with $P: r\mid s, Q:r\nmid t$. 
Further, assume $P$ to be fixed(tautology), then $Q: r\nmid t \implies C: s\nmid t$.

If use $P$ as tautology, need arrive at $\bot$ form by getting : $P \wedge \lnot P$.

> Request vetting the above line, for proving by the contra-diction based approach.

Can use the contrapositive approach to replace $Q\implies C$, by $\lnot C \implies \lnot Q$, with assumption that only divisibility relation in the propositions is reversed under negation.

So, the contrapositive leads to : $P \wedge \lnot C \implies \lnot Q$, this leads to : $r\mid s \wedge s\mid t \implies r\mid t$, which is true by the transitive property of the divisibility rule, i.e. $r\mid s \wedge s\mid t \implies r\mid t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For:

> "If $(r∣s) \text { and } (r∤t)$, then $(s∤t)$,

we must have:

> $(\exists k \ (s=rk) \land \forall m \ (t \ne rm)) \to \forall n \ (t \ne sn).$

---

If you want to prove it by contradiction, you have to assume the negation and derive a contradiciton.

The negation is:

> $(r∣s) \text { and } (r∤t) \text { and } (s∣t)$,

that is:

> > $\exists k \ (s=rk) \land \forall m \ (t \ne rm) \land \exists n \ (t=sn).$

From the first and the third conjunct we get:

> $(s=rk) \text { and } (t=sn), \text { i.e. } t=r(kn)$,

that contradicts the second conjunct.